# Pandas Mapping: add suffix based on tree structure

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-structures

**1. The Data:**

I have the following structure in a pandas DataFrame:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 'NaN', 'A', 'NaN'],['B', 'A', 'B/A', 'A'], ['B1', 'B', 'B1/B/A', 'B/A'], 
                     ['B2', 'B', 'B2/B/A', 'B/A'], ['C', 'B1', 'C/B1/B/A', 'B1/B/A'], ['D', 'B1', 'D/B1/B/A', 'B1/B/A'], 
                     ['E', 'B2', 'E/B2/B/A', 'B2/B/A']], 
                    columns=['unit_id', 'group_id', 'new_unit_id', 'new_group_id'])
```

**2. The issue and the goal:**

I would like to replace the current `unit_id` and `group_id` with a value that appends it's parent structure as basically:

`<unit_id> = <unit_id> + '/' + parent<unit_id>`
and
`<group_id> = parent<unit_id>`

as you would see in a file tree structure or similar.

Something like this:

| index | unit_id | group_id | new_unit_id | new_group_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | NaN | A | NaN |
| 1 | B | A | B/A | A |
| 2 | B1 | B | B1/B/A | B/A |
| 3 | B2 | B | B2/B/A | B/A |
| 4 | C | B1 | C/B1/B/A | B1/B/A |
| 5 | D | B1 | D/B1/B/A | B1/B/A |
| 6 | E | B2 | E/B2/B/A | B2/B/A |

**3. Attempts and approach:**

I have tried mapping in place without creating 'new' columns, but run into issues where when the `unit_id` of a parent changes, it is not reflected in the `group_id` of its children.

```py
df['unit_id'] = df['unit_id'] + '/' + df['group_id']
```

So it seems like I need to iterate row by row so the change on the previous row is factored in.  Something like:

```py
df['unit_id'] = df.apply(lambda row : row['unit_id'].replace(str(row['unit_id']), str(row['unit_id'] + '/' + row['group_id'])), axis=1)
```

This results in the same (inaccurate) values as above, but I think `df.apply` with the correct anonymous (lambda) function is a lot closer to what I need. Having trouble getting the syntax correct.

Comment: Are you guaranteed that the parent always comes before the child? For instance, could you have 'E' in D's group_id?

Comment: Yes, this is guaranteed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be approach using graph theory.

This is your graph:

[image]

You can use [`networkx`](https://networkx.org) to compute your graph and find the [`shortest_path`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.shortest_path.html):

```
import networkx as nx

# ensure real NaN
df = df.replace('NaN', np.nan)

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df.dropna(subset='group_id'),
                            source='unit_id', target='group_id',
                            create_using=nx.DiGraph)

#get final item
last = list(nx.topological_sort(G))[-1]

# get simple paths
df['new_unit_id'] = ['/'.join(nx.shortest_path(G, s, last))
                      if not pd.isna(s) else float('nan')
                      for s in df['unit_id']]

df['new_group_id'] = df['new_unit_id'].str.extract(r'[^/]+/(.+)')
```

output:

```
  unit_id group_id new_unit_id new_group_id
0       A      NaN           A          NaN
1       B        A         B/A            A
2      B1        B      B1/B/A          B/A
3      B2        B      B2/B/A          B/A
4       C       B1    C/B1/B/A       B1/B/A
5       D       B1    D/B1/B/A       B1/B/A
6       E       B2    E/B2/B/A       B2/B/A
```